# Bug when trying to recreate a ripple effect animation in a button (Material design)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to emulate a ripple effect when clicking in a button, but I got weird behaviour when happy clicking. I'm coding in vanilla JS for learning purposes. Please could anybody tell me where I've got it wrong?
Here's the full code:

#### Html

```
<button class="button button--ok ripple">Button</button>
<button class="button button--cancel ripple">Button</button>
```

#### Css

```
body {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0;
  font: "Helvetica neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.button--ok {
  background-color: #65DE65;
}

.button--cancel {
  background-color: tomato;
}


.circle {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.ripple.animate .circle {
    animation: ripple 2s;
}


@keyframes ripple {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
        opacity: .4;        
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(100);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

#### Js

```
var ripple = document.getElementsByClassName("ripple");

for (var i = 0; i < ripple.length; i++) {
    ripple[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // Store this for later
        var self = this;

        // Get x and y coordinates
        var x = e.offsetY+"px";
        var y = e.offsetX+"px";

        // Create the layer effect and apply a circle class,
        // then set coordinates
        var circle = document.createElement("div");
        circle.setAttribute("class", "circle");
        circle.style.top = x;
        circle.style.left = y;

        // Append layer effect to parent and add animate class
        // to start the animation
        self.appendChild(circle);
        self.className += " animate";

        // Remove layer effect once is done animating (2 seconds)
        setTimeout(function() {
            var elements = self.getElementsByClassName("circle");
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                 self.removeChild(elements[i]);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }, false);
}
```

Mine: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/vrico/pen/gpXKZa)
Disired: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Craigtut/pen/dIfzv)

Comment: Were you aware that public pens on codepen.io are already free to use under an [MIT license](http://blog.codepen.io/legal/licensing/)? I can't see much point in trying to debug your non-working code when you already have code that does exactly what you want. Besides, you don't seem to have made any effort to fix the bug in your own code. If you can, please reduce your code to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating the problem you're having. Otherwise this question is liable to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: If I use what is already done I wouldn't learn anything. I did try to fix it and that's why I asked for help, besides mine is raw JavaScript not jQuery, I already know how to use jQuery and It's great but I need to learn more.

I cleaned my code and It works better now, but still doesn't work as I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I see what you are trying to do and I too tried to explain the bizzare effect. Anyway I tried to do something and it worked, made the **.circle .animate** to simply **.animate** and changed the **scale(1)** to **scale(1,1)**, **scale(width,height)** setting.
Inside style the changes are:

```
.animate {
animation: ripple 2s forwards;
-webkit-animation-name:ripple;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes ripple {
from {
  transform: scale(1,1);
  opacity: 0.4;
}
to {
  transform: scale(100,100);
  opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqkx8so8/5/). For chrome and safari support added the -webkit- property.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That wasn't the problem. I solved the strange behaviour and it works much better now but it's not there yet. If we click several times sometimes the ripple effect starts at coordinates 0, 0.
I updated my code you can take a look if you want to. Thanks man!